# Why is $(1 - \frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}})^{n} < e^{-n^{\epsilon}}$ for $0 < \epsilon < 1$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, eulers-number-e

This argument appears in one proof in my lecture and I don't know why this holds. Maybe someone knows
a theorem that implies this inequality? Thanks for help.

Comment: I fixed the TeX in your title. It's nice though to have the question in the question, not just in the title.

Comment: Because $\ln(1+x)\leqslant x$

Comment: @Tuvasbien ... I should have seen this myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take $x=e^{-n^\varepsilon}$ then the inequality to be proved is
$$\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n<e^{-x}\tag1$$
where $x=n^{-\varepsilon}$. Taking logarithms, (1) is equivalent to
$$\ln\left(1-\frac xn\right)<-\frac xn\tag2$$
at least as long as $n>x$. This is the same as
$$\ln(1-y)<-y\tag3$$
for $y=x/n$. But (3) is valid for $0<y<1$; draw the graph and its tangent at $y=0$.